# YAML forming via Golang

Tags: go, yaml

Please help to fo create correct YAML structure.
I need to receive something like this :

```
groups:
  - name: Group1
    targets:
    - host1
    - host2
  - name: Group2
    targets:
    - host1
    - host2
```

And I have wrote the next code which is working but not correctly :

```
type YamlConfig struct {
    Groups struct {
            Name string `yaml:"name"`
            Targets []string `yaml:"targets"`
    } `yaml:"groups"`
}

var config YamlConfig
var hosts []string = []string{"host1", "host2"}
for host := range hosts {
    config.Groups.Name = "Group"+strconv.Itoa(host)
    config.Groups.Targets = hosts
}

y, err := yaml.Marshal(config)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Marshal: %v", err)
}

fmt.Println(string(y))
```

But this example is forming only this struct :

```
groups:
  name: Group1
  targets:
  - host1
  - host2
```

Please help to get the first result on correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your structure a little bit. As Group is a list, you need an array in go struct. Then when populating the data, create a new group and append to config.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {
    type Group struct {
        Name    string   `yaml:"name"`
        Targets []string `yaml:"targets"`
    }

    type YamlConfig struct {
        Groups []Group `yaml:"groups"`
    }

    var config YamlConfig
    var hosts []string = []string{"host1", "host2"}
    for host := range hosts {
        var group Group
        group.Name = "Group" + strconv.Itoa(host)
        group.Targets = hosts
        config.Groups = append(config.Groups, group)
    }

    y, err := yaml.Marshal(config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Marshal: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(y))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need an array/slice of `Group` so that your field "Groups" can have type `[]group` or `[]Group`. Do that with its own struct.

Something like:

```
type group struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
    Targets []string `yaml:"targets"`
}

type YamlConfig struct {
    Groups []group `yaml:"groups"`
}
```